# getMinBufferSize() when recording more than 1 sec with AudioRecord

Tags: android, buffer, audio-recording

I´m a bit confused using getMinBufferSize() and AudioRecord.read() while recording from the MIC of the phone.
I understand that getMinBufferSize() gives you the minimun amount of bytes required to create the audiorecord object (in 1 sec?).

```
bufferSize= AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
            RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
```

Then, when they call AudioRecord.read(), they have as an argument for the size of the bytes read "bufferSize".

```
read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);
```

Here are my questions:

1- Why bufferSize returns me 8192? I guess it´s making 8*1024 but I would like to know exactly what is the calculation that it is making (I´m using 8000 Hz sample rate, channel MONO and 16-bit PCM)

2- I suppose that bufferSize is the amount of data that I can store in 1 sec of duration but, what if I want to read more than 1 sec? Should I multiply this value to the number of seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a size of an array 8192
Since you encode your file in 16bit-PCM, the array size will be 16bit * 8192 which is around 130000
data capacity made in a second is 128000 ( = 8000 * 1 * 16)
so it becomes your min buffer size